# How to join 3 planes into one, for a floor that isnt square

Tags: modeling, workflow

I am making a room that has a weird floor. I split it into 3 sections when making the floor, but now when I try to combine the three planes with <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to combine grand, but one still has a line separating it and the other section of the floor.

How can I get them to combine without the line running through the middle?

[image]

Comment: There is gap, that's why you see the yellow line. Try to fix it in Edit Mode with the Snap Tool.

Comment: For the future, you might find it easier to create a single plane, then edit and SubDivide (face) into quadrants (or smaller).  Then you can extrude or move vertices or edges into the floor shape you want.   I realize one benefit for several planes might be to more quickly define sectional dimension -- but for a single subdivided plane, you can enable Edge Length in ViewPort Overlays, or (via Preferences) enable and apply "MeasureIt" Tools https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.91/addons/3d_view/measureit.html .

Comment: sure thanks, turns out there was a small gap as ffeller said, it worked now